# How to upgrade symfony2 version?

Tags: php, symfony, upgrade, symfony-2.1, composer-php

Is there a easy way to upgrade your symfony2.1.6 to 2.1.7 via command line or so? I am using composer.json

Comment: +1 because you dont deserve the down vote ! it is a good thing to answer your question and share your knowledge ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download `composer.phar` and then run in the symfony folder

```
php composer.phar update
```

If you get some errors try removing first the vendors and try again.  `rm - R vendor/*`

Comment: oh my bad I dint know. I thought it might help some one as I dont want anyone to spend hours like I did. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: With all due respect. I have been given a down vote, very strange, though this amazing forum itself gives an option to answer your own question right at the time posting it. I seriously need to understand how this forum works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it's completely normal to answer to your own questions on Stack Overflow.