# Symfony2 Upgrading 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: symfony, upgrade, symfony-2.2, symfony-2.3

I just read about the new Symfony-Release: [Symfony-Blog](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-3-0-the-first-lts-is-now-available). It says *'Upgrading from 2.2 to 2.3 should be painless.'*

As I only have one project and have upgraded that from 2.0 to 2.2 mainly by building-new-from-scratch, I am a little bit afraid of ***'should be'***.

My project is build with composer.

Which code has to be worked over and what exactly do I have to do migrate? I really can't find that on the symfony-site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read [upgrade](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/UPGRADE-2.3.md) readme file in symfony repository to see changes that can touch your code.

I am update one project from 2.1 to 2.3 and it was really painless. Update from 2.0 to 2.1 was very painful. Mostly it depends on vendor bundles, which will want to update to new versions.

**Update**

To update your application you must change you `composer.json` file. There is a [composer.json](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/composer.json) file from symfony-standard repository. You must change version in your `composer.json` file and run `php composer.phar update`. Example to update symfony core change `"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"`, to `"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*"`. But be careful, there are bundles depending between versions on each other. Example `doctrine-bundle v1.1` only works with symfony 2.1

**Update**(some of founded deprecates)

- **trust_proxy_headers** option is deprecated. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/configuration/framework.html#trust-proxy-headers).
- [MinLength](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/MinLength.html) and [MaxLength](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/MaxLength.html) validators is deprecated.
- [Min](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/Min.html) and [Max](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/constraints/Max.html) validators is deprecated.
- [Field](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/forms/types/field.html) form type removed.
- Some old twig blocks like `{% block field_row %}`, `{% block field_label %}` also removed(located in `form_div_layout.html.twig`).

**Symfony upgrade files**(just for convenience)

- [Symfony framework 2.1 -> 2.2 readme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md)
- [Symfony framework 2.2 -> 2.3 readme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md)
- [symfony-standard 2.1 -> 2.2 readme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md)
- [symfony-standard 2.2 -> 2.3 readme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md)

**Small hint**

To find the correct version is useful to use https://packagist.org. Example on [doctrine-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/doctrine-bundle) page, you can see which version suitable for 2.3 version.

Comment: Sorry, as it's the first time for me: Beside possible code-changes... how do I update symfony. Do I have to replace the existing composer.jar with a new one and do a composer-install? And will the removed packages be removed automatically? OK: Should be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924867/how-to-upgrade-symfony2-version

Comment: Thx. I searched for the files on the symfony-download-page. I think that's not the 'symfony-way', it could be easier :-)

Comment: You also need to ensure your app/bootstrap.php.cache file was updated.  Composer will usually do this but it does not hurt to check.

Comment: You need to delete the jms/extra entry from security.yml and manually delete the entries for JMSAopBundle in AppKernel.php in order to update without errors >_>